# Menu with mouseenter & mouseleave events

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent

**Introduction:**
Hello everyone. I am trying to do a menu, but i have problem with mouseenter/mouseleave events.

**What i have so far:**

```
$("#icon").click(function() {
    $("#invis").css("display", "block");
    $("#icon").bind("mouseleave", function(){
        $("#invis").css('display', "none");
    }).bind("mouseenter", function(){
        $("#invis").css('display', "block"); 
    });
    $("#invis").bind("mouseleave", function(){
        $("#invis").css('display', "none");
    }).bind("mouseenter", function(){
        $("#invis").css('display', "block");
    });
});​
```

So far, i tried this. My point is to click on the "icon", and this click would show a menu/another, hidden element. Now i want to keep it open as long, as someone keeps mouse over "icon" or actual menu. But with code i provided, once i leave my mouse and then enter again on "icon", it still keeps onmouseenter event, and menu will appear again. I know i could unbind onmouseenter event, but then once i drive off menu, onto icon, my menu would get closed, and i don't want that.

Simplest example i could think of: http://jsfiddle.net/tzzqM/5/

**Question**
How to make "menu" open on click event, and then keep it open as long as someone keeps mouse over menu or "icon" (both of them). Once mouse leaves area of both, menu closes, and to open it i need to click once more on "icon".
Is there a another way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On mouse leaving the object, check if the mouse is still either on the menu or on the menu-button, if not, hide the menu. Basically, you're binding the event `mouseleave` to both elements and then checking the length of the selection. If it's 1, you're either on the menu or the button, this makes the exiting the menu button into the menu itself, not trigger the "hidding" part of the code, if the selection length is 0, then we are not over any of those elements and we hide it.

```
$("#icon").click(function() {
    $("#invis").css("display", "block");
        $("#invis,#icon").bind("mouseleave", function(){
            if($("#invis:hover,#icon:hover").length === 0){
                $("#invis").css('display', "none");
            }
        })
});​
```

There's a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/F8hRD/1/).

Or the way I would write it if I had to start from scratch (just the jQuery part), since remember that you'd be jumping into the DOM pool less times and **should** be a little bit more efficient, although it's as functional as the first one. Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AMD6r/)

```
var icon = $("#icon"),
    menu = $("#invis");

icon.click(function() {
    menu.show();
        $.merge(icon,menu).bind("mouseleave", function(){
            if($("#icon:hover,#invis:hover").length < 1) menu.hide();
        });
});​
```

Or using the suggestion from **jhummel** we can access the id of the new view that has the hover, and check if it's one of the two that we want to monitor. This is great because it prevents us from jumping into the pool once more, this gives us a marginal performance boost, here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3abhm/1/).

```
var icon = $("#icon"),
    menu = $("#invis");

icon.click(function() {
    menu.show();
        $.merge(icon,menu).bind("mouseleave", function(e){
            if($.inArray(e.relatedTarget.id, ["icon","invis"]) === -1){
                   menu.hide();
            }
        });
});​
```

​

---

**Related docs:**

- [jQuery.merge](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.merge/)
- [Stop jumping into the pool!](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/quick-tip-jquery-newbs-stop-jumping-in-the-pool/)
- [jQuery.inArray](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/)
- [event.relatedTarget](http://api.jquery.com/event.relatedTarget/)

Comment: I like to link to the methods (not all of them, just the uncommon ones) used in my answers, so people actually read the docs. Glad I could help.

Comment: very nice! love the use of $.merge

Answer (score 1):

When you use `mouseover` or `mouseleave` events, the event object in jQuery will have a `relatedTarget` property. You can check that property to see if the mouse is entering the other element.

```
$("#icon").on('click',function() {
  $("#invis").show();
}).on('mouseleave', function(e) {
  if(e.relatedTarget.id != 'invis') $('#invis').hide();    
});

$('#invis').on('mouseleave', function(e) {
  if(e.relatedTarget.id != 'icon') $(this).hide();
});
```

[jquery relatedTarget docs](http://api.jquery.com/event.relatedTarget/)
​